# Accordion on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am running into an issue when it comes to turning my panel into an accordion when on mobile devices. Currently on desktop when you hover over the H3 tag with will display the div (.show-info) with an absolute positioning which follows my cursor. When scaling the browser down to 991 or lower the .show-info now displays under the h3 tag and no longer follows the cursor. However, for some reason I am unable to remove the hover effect and only use a click function so once I am on mobile and I click on the h3 tag it would slide down the .show-info and hide it when I click it again.

Here is my current code (HTML) also the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljdca6g2/1/)

```
<div class="about-item">
    <div class="about-item--1">
        <div class="about-text">
            <div class="panel-col-12 lg-title padding-tb-sm" id="hwdo-panel">
                <div class="w-60 right">
                    <ul id="hwdo-inner" data-animation="slideInUp">
                        <li>
                            <h3 data-hover="Details">Details</h3>
                            <div class="show-info">In everything that we do, our concise precision and meticulous eye distinguishes our work and elevates its impact.</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3 data-hover="Passion">Passion</h3>
                            <div class="show-info">To us, nothing is more important than passion. It is the lifeblood that guides our team and inspires us to make a difference every day.</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3 data-hover="Courage">Courage</h3>
                            <div class="show-info">Because nothing notable is ever created by playing it safe.</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3 data-hover="Care">Care</h3>
                            <div class="show-info">Above all, we give a shit: about our clients, about our work, and about each other.</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <div class="circle_btn wwd_btn ">
            <a href="aol.com" class="circle-arrow-btn">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/circle-arrow.svg" loading="arrow" alt="" class="circle-arrow">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/view-work-ring.svg" loading="ring" alt="" class="circle-ring">
                <div class="circle-btn-hover"></div>
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
#hwdo-panel {
position: relative;

ul {
    font-weight: 900;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;     
    
    &:hover > li {
        opacity:0.1;
        
        @media (max-width:992px) {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    
    li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        -webkit-transition:0.5s;
                      transition:0.5s;
        
        @media (min-width:992px) {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
        }
    
        &:hover{
            opacity:1;
        }

        &:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        &:hover .show-info {
            display: block;
        }   

        .show-info {
            position: relative;
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
            font-weight: 500;
            
            @media (min-width:992px) {
                display: none;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                position: absolute;
                background: var(--pink);
                padding: 2em;
                font-weight: 500;
                width: 60%;
                z-index: 90;
            }
            
            @media (min-width:1024px) {
                width: 40%;
            }
        }

        h3 {
            position: relative;
            color: transparent;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
            -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;

            &:before {
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 0;
                color: var(--pink);
                content: attr(data-hover);
            }

            &:hover:before {
                width: 100%;     
                transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.32, 0.87);
            }

            &:after {
                content: '+';
                position: relative;
                float: right;
                font-size: .5em;
                color: var(--white);
                -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
                -webkit-text-stroke-color: transparent;
                font-weight: 500;
            }
            &:hover:after {
                color: var(--pink);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // handle click event on h3 element
    $('#hwdo-panel ul li h3').click(function() {
        // check if screen is small
        if ($(window).width() < 991) {
            // use a CSS selector to find the corresponding figure element
            let figure = $(this).siblings('.show-info');
            // toggle its visibility
            figure.toggleClass('show');
            // close other figures
            $('#hwdo-panel .show-info').not(figure).removeClass('show');
        }
    });

    // handle mousemove event on large screens
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        // check if screen is large
        if ($(window).width() >= 991) {
            // use a CSS selector to detect the hover state:
            let figure = $('#hwdo-panel ul li:hover .show-info');
            // now do your positioning
            if (figure.length) {
                let x = e.pageX,
                    y = e.pageY,
                    w = figure.outerWidth(),
                    h = figure.outerHeight(),
                    maxX = $(window).width() - w - 10, // 10px margin
                    left = (x + 50 > maxX) ? (x - w - 50) : (x + 50);
                figure.offset({
                    top: (y + 0),
                    left: left
                });
            }
        }
    });

    // handle hover event on li elements on large screens
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 991) {
            $('#hwdo-panel ul li').hover(function() {
                // use a CSS selector to find the corresponding figure element
                let figure = $(this).find('.show-info');
                // display the figure
                figure.addClass('show');
            }, function() {
                // use a CSS selector to find the corresponding figure element
                let figure = $(this).find('.show-info');
                // hide the figure
                figure.removeClass('show');
            });
        } else {
            $('#hwdo-panel ul li').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
        }
    }).resize();
});
```